# How do I install bind9 with dlz dlopen drivers included?

Tags: samba, dns

I'm currently installing samba4 as for a -extra own chosen- schoolproject. I'm following the HOWTO installation from [their website](http://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba4/HOWTO). Now, I'm stuck at getting my dns working.

I've installed bind9 with `sudo apt-get install bind9` (version 9.7.x). I've added the samba4 named.conf file to my named.conf.local `using include "/usr/local/samba/private/named.conf";`.

Now when i try to restart my bind9 service using `sudo /etc/init.d/bind9 restart` I get the following error:

> Unsupported DLZ database driver 'dlopen'.

I've googled the problem and all i could find was that my current version from bind9 didn't had dlz for dlopen. So i've downloaded BIND9 9.8.0P1 from the ics.org website and did `sudo ./configure --with-dlz-dlopen` and then `sudo make` and then `sudo make install`.

Now I thought this should fix the problem but the problem still exists. Named -v give me version 9.8.0P1. All this is configured on the newest Ubuntu (11.10).

So to make the question small: How do I install bind9 with dlz dlopen drivers included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11380598) forum post has a tutorial to do what you are attempting.

Comment: Thank you for your help but it's not what i'm looking for. In the forum post they tell you everything about dlz in combination with mysql, postgresql, bdb, etc. Only I need it in combination with dlopen.

Answer (score 0):

You need bind9 version 9.8.X to make it work and configure it with ->

./configure --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc/bind --localstatedir=/var --mandir=/usr/share/man --enable-threads --with-libtool && make && make install

add the named.conf from the samba dirs to the bind9 named.conf (include it).

And fix /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.named to access the needed files.

/usr/local/samba/private/* rw,

/usr/local/samba/private/dns/* rw,

I still have to fix some minor probs but at least samba4 does DNS updates. If you already made  a db file with your domain you must remove it or you get an error it is already defined.

Watch your /var/log/syslog for messages from bind or apparmor.